# Stubbing with sinon.stub in meteor.js using local modules

Tags: node.js, meteor, sinon, stub

I am having trouble doing some basic stubbing with sinon, for unit testing. When the stubbed method is eventually called, it is calling the real method rather than the stubbed version.

I have created a simple version of this to illustrate the problem I'm dealing with. I am running meteor 1.6.1 and using the `meteortesting` package using the command `meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha`, the following files are all inside the `/server` directory. I use `module.exports` instead of export on the module thats being stubbed because an error is thrown otherwise (a seperate bug, `import * as foo from './file'` should work).

Interestingly, the stub works correctly if I export in `calc-module.js` using export default, the problem is that I am working in a large production app, and I'd like to avoid using export default throughout just for stubbing purposes.

I have tried almost identical code in node 8, and it works fine.

```
//calc-module.test.js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { runAdd5 } from './wrappers';
import calcModule from  './calc-module';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('calcModule', () => {
    before(() => {
        sinon.stub(calcModule, 'add5').callsFake((number) => {
            return number
        });
    });
    it('stubbed add5 causes function to not add anything', () => {
        const result = runAdd5(0)
        expect(result).to.eql(0)
    });
});


//calc-module.js
const add5 = (number) => {
    return number + 5
}

module.exports = {
    add5
}

//wrappers.js
import { add5 } from './calc-module';

const runAdd5 = (number) => {
    return add5(number)
};

export {
    runAdd5
};
```

Comment: I think it is because you're using module.exports, since they don't offer the same live bindings that ESModules do

Comment: module.exports should work fine for stubbing in general, I use that successfully in a node version of the same code. Also I said above, export is not an options due to a separate meteor bug in 1.6.1 that I believe is due to how meteor transpiles.